# List all stopped AWS EC2 instances with command line toolkit

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have been experimenting around with `ec2-describe-instances` and `ec2-describe-instance-status` in the EC2 command line tools with the goal of starting stopped instances. However I cannot neatly list all stopped instances. `ec2-describe-instance-status` only lists running instances (unless I am doing something wrong).

Is there an easier way to list stopped instances than awk-ing the hell out of `ec2-describe-instances`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command to list the stopped instances.

> ec2-describe-instances --filter "instance-state-name=stopped"

Comment: Excellent! That's half the battle won! Having that pre-filter will make awk-ing the output easier anyway. Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ruby script I've written for some purposes that uses the aws gem:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'aws'

ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(
:access_key_id => 'AWS_KEY',
:secret_access_key => 'AWS_SECRET')

ec2.regions.each do |region|
 ec2.regions["#{region.name}"].instances.each do |line|
  if line.status.to_s=="stopped"
   puts("#{line}") #check docs for what exactly you need to output
  end
 end
end
```

You can modify it for your own purposes to get all the data you need. Just check the docs at https://github.com/grempe/amazon-ec2 (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: I would prefer if there was a stand alone solution that doesn't require additional libraries. Also, I'm not immediately familiar with Ruby, so that is another layer removed! Cheers for the link though, I now have a fall back :D

Answer (score 0):

ec2-describe-instances --filter "instance-state-name=stopped" | ec2-start-instances -

The "-" tells ec2-start-instances to read from stdin.

Answer (score -1):

> ec2-describe-instance-status --filter "instance-state-name=stopped"

This will only provide youlist of stopped instances.

Comment: This maybe something about my setup that needs debugging, but `ec2-describe-instance-status` only lists running instances. Is this right? should it list stopped instances?

Comment: no, it also lists stopped instances as well. try this command and see yourself

Comment: I have run the command, and as I say, stopped instances are not listed, it does list all running though. With the filtered argument, nothing is returned.

Comment: you are making some mistake for sure, as this script surely shows the instances which are stopped, i have checked it on my AWS account already. its showing stopped instanced

Comment: ec2-describe-instance-status only lists instances in the "Running" state.  See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstanceStatus.html

Comment: Try ec2-describe-instances --filter "instance-state-name=stopped"